# How to connect a Flutter App with a Secondary Firebase Web App?

Tags: flutter, firebase-realtime-database

My App was developed with Flutter and Firebase RTDB (Database 1). It was build for IOS and Android.

I have a secondary App that was developed with JS and Firebase RTDB (Database 2). It was created for the Web.

Now, I would like to write to Database 2 from my Flutter App. What should I do step by step?

I tried to apply [Add Multiple Projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56921727/flutter-how-to-add-multiple-firebase-projects-to-my-flutter-project) using something like:

```
Future<void> _initSecondaryFirebaseDB() async {

    await Firebase.initializeApp(
    name: 'SecondaryQRApp',
    options: const FirebaseOptions(
        appId: 'APP Id 847597056ab2f26',
        apiKey: 'Api Key InXspCU',
        messagingSenderId: 'messagingSenderId 35345',
        projectId: 'projectId of Web App'
    )
);
```

But I'm not sure if it's a secure procedure and I don't know how to call the secondary database instance...

```
 DatabaseReference db2 = FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference(); 
//It wouldn't work because I have a Primary or Default Database in my Flutter App
```

What do I need to do step y step to connect my Flutter App with the secondary Firebase RTDB (Database 2)?

Comment: Why is the web app connecting to a different database? If you have it connect to the same database, it will immediately be able to see changes by the mobile apps. For a demo of this, see https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rwrUezKCc34&feature=youtu.be for the (native and web) code, see https://github.com/puf/firevotes

Comment: @puf It's a good question and I'm not 100% convinced of the answer, but there it goes ... I have a second database because it is public. That is why I think it is safer to keep separate databases, and not give url web access options to the first database.

Comment: Now you're going to have to synchronize data between the two databases, which sounds like the wrong kind of hole to dig for yourself. If you have a public section and a private section in the same database, you can just write different [security rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security) for them (always a good idea).

Comment: If you really want the Flutter app to connect to two realtime databases that is possible, and the code you shared seems a good starting point for that. What is the problem you have when you run that code? Ah, I see now... you're getting the app the wrong way. I'll write up an example below.'

Comment: You're probably right about the hole that I'm digging, jejeje. For now, I only need to write one document at a time from the App and not modify it. In fact, I am thinking that in the future it should be a Blockchain database to be immutable ... any ideas from Firebase?

Answer (score 3):

When you call `FirebaseDatabase.instance` you're getting the default instance of the database. To get the instance for a specific configuration, you need to pass in the `FirebaseApp` instance for that configuration.

```
var app = await Firebase.initializeApp(
  name: 'SecondaryQRApp',
  options: const FirebaseOptions(
    appId: 'APP Id 847597056ab2f26',
    apiKey: 'Api Key InXspCU',
    messagingSenderId: 'messagingSenderId 35345',
    projectId: 'projectId of Web App'
  )
);
var db = FirebaseDatabase(app: app);
```

If you don't have the `app` instance ready, you can look it up by its name:

```
var app = FirebaseApp.apps.firstWhere(app => app.name == "SecondaryQRApp");
```

Comment: Thank you @puf. The sentence  'var db = FirebaseDatabase(app);' is throwing me an error: Too many positional arguments: 0 expected, but 1 found.

Comment: ah, it looks like it's a named parameter indeed. Updated in my answer, and also see https://pub.dev/documentation/firebase_database/latest/