# How to share authentication between default Firebase app and secondary Firebase app in flutter?

Tags: firebase, flutter, google-cloud-firestore

My flutter application is using two instances of different FirebaseApp. The default FirebaseApp is used for authentication in the app. Now I need to access data from FirebaseFirestore from Secondary FirebaseApp. The source of data for Secondary FirebaseApp is another flutter application. I managed to set up my project to use two instances of FirebaseApp using the following code.

```dart
@module
abstract class RegisterModule {
  @preResolve
  Future<FirebaseApp> get firebaseApp => Firebase.initializeApp();

  @singleton
  FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth() => FirebaseAuth.instance;

  @Named("secondary")
  @preResolve
  Future<FirebaseApp> get adminFirebaseApp => Firebase.initializeApp(
        name: 'admin',
        options: const FirebaseOptions(
          appId: 'app-id',
          apiKey: 'api-key',
          messagingSenderId: 'messaging-sender-id',
          projectId: 'project-id',
        ),
      );

  @Named("secondary")
  @singleton
  FirebaseFirestore adminFirestore(
          @Named("secondary") FirebaseApp firebaseApp) =>
      FirebaseFirestore.instanceFor(app: firebaseApp);
}
```

This works fine as long as I set `allow read, write: if true;` in Rules in CloudFirestore of Secondary firebase project but won't work if I set the rule to only allow authenticated user.

```
rules_version = '2';
service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /{document=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Basically same issue as mentioned in the first answer of this thread [Flutter: How to add multiple Firebase projects to my Flutter project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56921727/flutter-how-to-add-multiple-firebase-projects-to-my-flutter-project)
.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Why are you using a secondary `FirebaseApp` instance? Is it accessing another project?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen yeah. Another application is the source of data for that second Firebase app. Two different applications. Users are different, data are different.

Comment: So in that case you'll need to log into the second secondary app with a separate call: `FirebaseAuth.instanceFor(adminFirebaseApp)...`.