# Firebase multiple location database projects for one application

Tags: firebase, flutter

Firestore lets you choose geographic location for database I think I am in India and choose relevant location for my database. The queries or reads are much faster. Now the question comes here I am building an app for globe. In that can I create multiple Firebase/firestore projects and linked them with one app is it good idea to do. Is it possible to linked it with flutter somehow or having multiple Firebase projects for one app is a problem for Firebase or play store

Comment: Check out [ask] to improve this question

Comment: Thanks I will remember next time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think using multiple projects for a single app is great idea as you'll have to replicate the data across them. I personally haven't encountered any major difference whether I use any region in US or in Asia. It's usually a few milliseconds at max.

However, if most of your users are in India and then you should probably consider selecting any region in Asia. If you need more availability then you should consider any multi-regional location (only 2 are available at the moment i.e. US and Europe).

You can [initialize multiple Firebase projects](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56921727/flutter-how-to-add-multiple-firebase-projects-to-my-flutter-project) in a single application but as mentioned earlier you would have to figure out the region (or project) closest to the user and then connect to that specific project and also replicate the data in both which I'm not sure if is worth doing.

Comment: Can you please check out my question if possible https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68351097/reading-firebase-storage-image-security-rules