# Connect multiple firebase projects to the same flutter desktop app

Tags: windows, flutter, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, flutter-windows

I am building a windows desktop app using flutter. I hava 2 firebase projects I want to connect with. First one I am using for authentication (log in using email and password) and for that I am using the package [firedart](https://pub.dev/packages/firedart/example). Then Within the app I want to retrieve some data from another firebase project (an existing firebase project connected with a mobile app).

here is how I am connecting to the first project:

```
import 'package:firedart/firedart.dart';

const apiKey = "xyz";
const projectId = "xyz";

void main() {
  FirebaseAuth.initialize(apiKey, VolatileStore());
  Firestore.initialize(projectId);
  runApp(const MyApp());

}
```

Normally, If i want to connect to firestore from windows app in flutter using firedart then I can do something like this:

```
var ref = Firestore.instance.collection('test').document('doc');
```

But what I want is to make the connection to to the firestore from a different firebase project.

Any suggestions on how can I do that?

Comment: Not exactly using `fideart` but it might help solve your problem as well: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56921727/flutter-how-to-add-multiple-firebase-projects-to-my-flutter-project

Comment: @ArturA Thank you for your answer. I have seen this question before but the answers there doesnt seem to work for me. note that I cant use the official firestore package because its not supported in flutter windows

Comment: Hi, for anyone who is interested in the official flutterfire desktop. please upvote for the feature request in the link below. thanx!
https://firebase.uservoice.com/forums/948424-general/suggestions/46591750-desktop-windows-linux-macos-support-for-flutte